# Can't update node when use homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

When I use "brew upgrade node"

> brew upgrade node Warning: You are using a pre-release version of
>   Xcode. You may encounter build failures or other breakages. Please
>   create pull-requests instead of filing issues. Error: node not
>   installed

But when I use "brew info node"

> Please note by default only English locale support is provided. If you
>   need full locale support you should either rebuild with full icu:
>   `brew reinstall node --with-full-icu` or add full icu data at runtime
>   following:
>   https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl#using-and-customizing-the-small-icu-build

Comment: The second output doesn't imply that node is installed. Did you try `brew install node`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fully functional version of `node`.

Try it for yourself and see what you get. I would expect something like:

```
> which node
/usr/local/bin/node
> node -v
v6.7.0
```

The first error is the interesting bit. Looks like you are on xcode 8.0 before it was released and maybe it did cause issues with upgrading node. I presume with the public launch of xcode, this is no longer an issue.

The `brew info node` caveat is just letting you know that you have a working version of `node`, but with english only.